# Cargar datos en un formulario PHP sin perder los datos ingresados

Tags: php

Buen día.

A continuación, relaciono el inconveniente:

El sistema me arroja `Undefined index` al momento de cargar los datos, la particularidad es la siguiente:

Tengo un formulario llamado **prenovedades.php** que recibe unos datos, los cuales son recibidos por un formulario llamado **novedades.php** (hasta ahí todo funciona perfecto).

Mediante `ajax`, llamo otro formulario que se llama **descuento.php** y recibe un dato de **novedades.php** (esto funciona perfectamente), pero al dar `click` en cancelar, me devuelve al formulario **novedades.php** y me genera el error de `Undefined index`. El fragmento de código de **novedades.php** donde recibe los parámetros es el siguiente:

```
$Documento = $_POST['Documento'];
$Concepto = $_POST['Concepto'];
$Ano = $_POST['Ano'];
$Mes = $_POST['Mes'];
$periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
$ID_Novedad = $Documento. $Ano. $Mes. $periodo;
```

El fragmento de código de **descuento.php**, donde redirecciona a novedades es:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-lg" id="btn-altas"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Registrar</button>
    <a href = "ll_tbnovedades.php?Documento='<?php echo $Documento;?>'" ><button type="button" method="post" class="btn btn-danger btn-raised btn-lg" id="btn-alta-cancela"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Cancelar</button></a>
```

Les quedaría muy agradecido si me pueden sacar de este apuro.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Juan el botón de cancel que es el que te regresa a los datos anteriores, lo estas haciendo con ajax por que si es así seria bueno que colocaras el código completo. Gracias

Comment: Buen día Yoel, el formulario descuento.php, lo llamo mediante una función que está en el formulario novedades.php, el código es el siguiente: function addDescuento(ID_Novedad,Documento) {
   
      $('#nuevoDescuento').load('ll_tbdescuentonew.php?ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad+ '&Documento='+ Documento);
  }

Comment: Ya encontre la solución, fue necesario agregar lo siguiente en novedad.php                                         if(isset($_GET['ID_Novedad'])) {
     $ID_Novedad = $_GET['ID_Novedad']; 
  $Documento = $_GET['Documento'];
  $Ano = $_GET['Ano'];
  $Mes = $_GET['Mes'];
$periodo = $_GET['periodo'];
$Concepto = $_GET['Concepto'];
  } else{
       $Documento = $_POST['Documento'];
    $Concepto = $_POST['Concepto'];
$Ano = $_POST['Ano'];
$Mes = $_POST['Mes'];
$periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
$ID_Novedad = $Documento. $Ano. $Mes. $periodo; 
  }